# React-Native, how to get permissions programmatically?

Tags: react-native, permissions

Say, I want to use Camera, but before opening Camera, App will request user permission.

If user deny to use camera, how can we know that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way of doing this in React Native so you would need to create a Native Module which exposes `AVCaptureDevice` to the Javascript layer of your app. Here is how to do that: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

You could also use a third-party npm package for that.

You can check the authorization status of the `AVCaptureDevice` using the `authorizationStatus` method.

You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624613-authorizationstatus

If you want to check if user pressed `Deny` you can do it in the completion handler of the `AVCaptureDevice` method `requestAccess`.

You can read about that here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624584-requestaccess

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not another solution, I will use `react-native-permissions` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to install android permission `npm install react-native-android-permissions --save`.

Comment: and what about iOS ?